# Force Android WebView to open in new browser

Tags: android, android-webview

Android has changed its default method for opening clicks, it now opens them in the webview instead of a new browser. This has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384384/android-webview-not-launching-new-browser) but every thing I have tried opens the links in the WebView. Can someone give me details on capturing the clicks so I con force the `link to open in the default browser`.

Comment: "Android has changed its default method for opening clicks, it now opens them in the webview instead of a new browser" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly?

Comment: All I know is that with the same app my older phone running Android 2.3.7 opens the links in the default browser and my new phone 4.0.4 opens the links in the webview. I don't know why I just know it does.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your button onclick:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
```

startActivity(browserIntent);

For it to parse it needs a *http://* at the start.

Comment: If this answer helped you mark it as correct to help other users find it

Answer (score 0):

Finally working don't know if it is the best way but it works. I placed the following code inside the onCreate. The string strSiteUrl set to the page I want the WebView to show.

```
/* Load WebView in memory */
WebView webv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webv);
webv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent();
        browserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        return false;
    }
}); //End webv.setVewView
/* Configure WebView */
    WebSettings webSettings = webv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);                
    webv.loadUrl(strSiteUrl);
```

When a user clicked on a link in the WebView page it would open the default browser and show the linked page. However, after clicking the back button depending on which link was clicked the WebView would return to the original page or show the linked page. This is not what I wanted, I only wanted the WebView to show the original page. I don't know why some links didn't return correctly, maybe those links were redirects? So to get around this problem I used the onStart call. I made the view webv global by placing

```
WebView webv;
```

in my global declarations. Changed the webv assignment to

```
webv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webv);
```

Then created the following onStart

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String strReturnUrl = String.valueOf(webv.getUrl());
    Log.i("URL!", strReturnUrl);
    if (!strReturnUrl.contentEquals(strSiteUrl)) { 
        webv.loadUrl(strSiteUrl);
    }
}
```

Writing to the log the returned url proved that when the back button was pressed it returned with different urls depending on which link was clicked. I used the if statement to prevent unnecessary reloading of the original url.